# TextEdit Binding becomes null after binding InputBindings

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I had a button and TextEdit like this, they were working correctly:

```
<dxe:TextEdit Text="{Binding SearchText}" />
<Button Command="{Binding SearchCommand}" / >
```

I wanted to make search when user hits Enter, so I changed my code this way :

```
<dxe:TextEdit Text="{Binding SearchText}"  >
                    <dxe:TextEdit.InputBindings>
                        <KeyBinding Key="Enter" Command="{Binding SearchCommand}"  />
                    </dxe:TextEdit.InputBindings>
                </dxe:TextEdit>
<Button Command="{Binding SearchCommand}">
```

This works, but in the code, **SearchText** is always null. So I broke something when I added input bindings, can you tell me how to fix this?
I also tried this one, but SearchText is still null.

```
<KeyBinding Key="Enter" Command="{Binding SearchCommand}"  CommandParameter="{Binding Path=Text, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type dxe:TextEdit}}}" />
```

Comment: Can you add UpdateSourceTrigger to Text property and set it to PropertyChanged and see if it works?

Comment: Nice. Will add as an answer incase it helps anyone else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I remember correctly the default UpdateSourceTrigger property for DevExpress editors is LostFocus (I might be wrong on this)

And to make your code work, you have to force the source to update whenever the target value changes, by setting UpdateSourceTrigger to PropertyChangted.

```
Text="{Binding GetIPag.TextQuery,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged,Mode=TwoWay}"
```

You can read more about UpdateSourceTrigger property on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.binding.updatesourcetrigger(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Thanks, you just saved me a lot of work. Try to be less patronizing though.

Answer (score 1):

Have you nofity about change in code? You have to do it by inheriting INotifyPropertyChanged interface in your class and invoke PropertyChangedEventHandler event;